# MKAnnotationView leftCalloutAccessoryView Autolayout

Tags: ios, autolayout, mkannotationview

I am trying to add a custom view as the `leftCalloutAccessoryView` in my custom `MKAnnotationView`.  All of the examples I have found use either an image, or some type of view where the frame is specified on init.  I want to use autolayout for the view.

This is the code I have in my init method for my`MKAnnotationView`. I am just trying to use simple width and height constraints:

```
UIView* contentView = [[UIView alloc] init];
contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

NSLayoutConstraint* height = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:32];

NSLayoutConstraint* width = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:contentView
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                              relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                 toItem:nil
                                                              attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                             multiplier:1
                                                               constant:50];

[contentView addConstraints:@[height,width]];
self.leftCalloutAccessoryView = contentView;
```

I can never get the view to show up with constraints. If I remove the constraints and init the view with a frame it will show up. What do I need to do to get constraints working with the `leftCalloutAccessoryView`?

Also, if I change `leftCalloutAccessoryView` to `detailCalloutAccessoryView`, which was added in iOS 9, and it shows up correctly.